# Calculate acceleration knowing initial speed, required speed, and distance to cover

Tags: convergence-acceleration

How to get the acceleration in m/s by knowing the initial speed, required speed and the distance by which this required speed is to be achieved.

Basically I am developing a car simulation program, and I want the car to match the speed of another car by the time it gets to it.

So for example my car is driving at speed 20m/s and there is a vehicle driving at 10m/s which is 100m away. What acceleration should I have to gradually change my speed so that by the time my car reaches the other car the speed of my car will be that of the other.

Comment: Do you know $v'^2-v^2=2ax$?

Comment: No, what is x here and what is v'

Comment: $v'$ is the required speed and $v$ is the initial speed, $a$ is acceleration, $x$ is the distance (or **displacement** to be exact) covered between.

Comment: @vim: where come from your formula?

Comment: I shall post a (simple) proof in my post below. Just a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Here a proof with only elemental algebra.

Let $v_1,s_1$ be the initial velocity and initial position of the first car, and $v_2,s_2$ those of the second car. The first car accelerate (or decelerate, depending on the particular situation) with a uniform acceleration $a$.
The equation of motion for the first car is:
$$
s=\dfrac{1}{2}at^2+v_1t+s_1
$$
and his velocity is $v=at+v_1$.

For the second car we have
$$
s=v_2t+s_2 \qquad v=v_2 \qquad (constant)
$$
So, the time when the two cars are in the same position is given by:
$$
\dfrac{1}{2}at^2+v_1t+s_1=v_2t+s_2
$$
solving this equation we find:
$$
t=\dfrac{v_2-v_1 \pm \sqrt{(v_1-v_2)^2-2a(s_1-s_2)}}{a}
$$
Note that the discriminant can always be $>0$, choosing a suitable $a$, so the equation has real solutions whatever be the initial velocities and positions.
Only we have to choose the solution with $t>0$ and this depend on initial velocities. Anyway, we are searching the time when the velocity $v=at+v_1$ of the first car is the same $v_2$ of the second, so  we pose:
$$
at+v_1=v_2 \Rightarrow v_2-v_1\pm \sqrt{(v_1-v_2)^2-2a(s_1-s_2)}+v_1=v_2
$$
So, simplifing and squaring we find the formula:
$$
(v_1-v_2)^2=2a(s_1-s_2) \Rightarrow a=\dfrac{(v_1-v_2)^2}{2(s_1-s_2)}
$$
that solve the problem.

Comment: I suppose it should be $$v_1^2-v_2^2=2a(s_1-s_2)$$ in your last equation.

Comment: It seems to me that my result is the same of that in your ansver. Your $v$ is the **relative** velocity, i.e. $v=v_1-v_1$. So why the downvote? where is the mistake?

Comment: I have cancelled the downvote. But mine is of course not the relative v.

Answer (score 0):

In uniform acceleration motion:
$$v(t)=v(0)+at$$
where $v(0)$ is the initial velocity and $a$ the acceleration (a constant).
Differenciate both sides by $t$:
$$dv(t)=adt$$
Multiply both sides by $v(t)$
$$v(t) \cdot dv(t)=a\cdot v(t)dt=a\cdot dx(t)$$
where $x(t)$ denotes the displacement from $t=0$.
Integrate both sides
$$v^2(t)-C=2a\cdot x(t)$$
where $C$ is the integral constant depending on the initial condition, and it is easy to find that $C=v^2 (0)$ to satisfy the initial condition.

Comment: I agree. But why the difference of two square in your comment? i suppose it was a typo...

Comment: Its' the difference of the speed square.

Comment: Seing your answer it seems to me that it must be the square of the difference instead. I'm wrong?

Comment: @EmilioNovati because I was integrating $vdv$ so it must be $\frac12\Delta v^2$.

Comment: @EmilioNovati I was dealing with the "natural" but not the relative velocity.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what you means for ''natural'' velocity.

Comment: I am not quite familiar with terminology, in fact I mean the velocity whose reference is the earth or something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21219/discussion-between-emilio-novati-and-vim).